# How to list only the file names and not its attributes in a directory( in Linux)?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a bash script to automatically change the desktop background by selecting from the images in a given directory.The problem I am facing is that when I try to use the "ls" command to list the images, it also shows its attributes.Is there a way that I could only list the file names and none of its other attributes.

Here, if if TEST_DIR= /home/vivek/Downloads
then

```
ls $TEST_DIR/*.jpeg -o $TEST_DIR/*.png -o $TEST_DIR/*.jpg
```

gives output as

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vivek   7221 Sep  5 20:42 /home/vivek/Downloads/viv.jpeg
```

I just need the output as "/home/vivek/Downloads/viv.jpeg".

EDIT:

The script works just fine after removing the "-o" from the command.

Earlier I was using "-o" to denote an "or" keyword.

But now,

`ls $TEST_DIR/*.jpeg $TEST_DIR/*.png $TEST_DIR/*.jpg`

gives me exactly the output I needed. Thanks.

Comment: There are programs that do this already. And if that's your output from `ls` that's an alias. Have you tried `ls` in a script and seen that output? Also `-o` isn't an argument to `ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `-o` to `ls` (twice, even). Remove that, because it means:

> ```
>       -o     like -l, but do not list group information
> ```

You can also shorten it to:

```
ls $TEST_DIR/*.{jpeg,png,jpg}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `cut` command as follows;

```
ls $TEST_DIR/*.{jpeg,png,jpg}|cut -d':' -f2|cut -d' ' -f2
```

It will exclude unwanted text using `:` and space to find result.

It will give you this **output**:

```
/home/vivek/Downloads/viv.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ls` is probably [aliased](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) to something. See what this prints:

```
$ alias ls
```

It should work fine from a script, because aliases are ignored there by default.

Comment: This is what I get...
" alias ls='ls --color=auto' "

Comment: In that case... I added a better answer :)